# Using JSoup to log in on URL (Java)

Tags: java, jsoup

I'm trying to log on a webpage on the usual way, to webscrape/exctract data. Everything works fine with the log-in-part, but the response I get is the HTML page where it says 'Loging you in, please wait'.

The return page I want is the last in the 'sequence'.

Is there any way to skip this? Anything I have missed?

Sorry if this is a duplicate, I have read around StackOverflow without finding something like this.

The code looks like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ParseException{
    final String USER_AGENT = "\"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT\" +\n" +
    "          \" 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/15.0.874.120 Safari/535.2\"";
    String username = "xxx";
    String password = "xxx";
    HashMap<String, String> cookies = new HashMap<>();
    HashMap<String, String> formData = new HashMap<>();
    String loginFormUrl = "https://id.ice.no/oauth2/account/login?returnUrl=%2Foauth2%2Fconnect%2Fauthorize%2Fcallback%3Fclient_id%3DSelfService%26redirect_uri%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fminside.ice.no%252Fsignin-callback.html%26response_type%3Did_token%2520token%26scope%3Dopenid%2520profile%2520roles%2520SelfService%26state%3D7f6047df0ddd4949b2992761ed98dd3b%26nonce%3Dbfc111c39548438c9a39b327c745947f%26acr_values%3DreturnUrl%2520Lw%253D%253D";
    String loginActionUrl= "https://id.ice.no/oauth2/account/login?returnUrl=%2Foauth2%2Fconnect%2Fauthorize%2Fcallback%3Fclient_id%3DSelfService%26redirect_uri%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fminside.ice.no%252Fsignin-callback.html%26response_type%3Did_token%2520token%26scope%3Dopenid%2520profile%2520roles%2520SelfService%26state%3D6ef2cad2efd24b3db7d61343aacc29f5%26nonce%3Db8b29eea53ae4952b8ffec5c43a9882a%26acr_values%3DreturnUrl%2520L2Fib25uZW1lbnQvMTYxODYwNjIvc2VuZHNtcw%253D%253D";
    Connection.Response loginForm = Jsoup.connect(loginFormUrl).method(Connection.Method.GET).userAgent(USER_AGENT).execute();
    Document loginDoc = loginForm.parse(); // this is the document that contains response html
    cookies.putAll(loginForm.cookies()); // save the cookies, this will be passed on to next request

    formData.put("username", username);
    formData.put("Password", password);
    String authToken = loginDoc.select("#form > input[type=hidden]:nth-child(8)")
      .first()
      .attr("value");
    formData.put("__RequestVerificationToken", authToken);

    Connection.Response homePage = Jsoup.connect(loginActionUrl)
   .cookies(cookies)
   .data(formData)
   .method(Connection.Method.POST)
   .userAgent(USER_AGENT)
   .execute();


   System.out.println(homePage.parse().html());
```

Comment: share your code so that some one could help you out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's difficult to say without having real login and password to check what's going on there so I'll have to guess. Few remarks:

1. Input with username has name `Username`, but you're setting formData with `username`. This may cause problems.
2. Login form has few inputs but you're only putting username, Password and token. This may cause problems. You should always include all fields, so you're missing:

```
String returnUrl = loginDoc.select("input[name=ReturnUrl]").first().attr("value");
formData.put("ReturnUrl", returnUrl);
formData.put("RememberLogin", "false");
formData.put("button", "login");
```

It's always a good idea to user browser's debugger to see what data is really submitted:
[image]

3. It's not a problem if it works, but I don't like how you get the token. Instead of:

```
String authToken = loginDoc.select("#form > input[type=hidden]:nth-child(8)").first().attr("value");
```

You can simply use:

```
String authToken = loginDoc.select("input[name=__RequestVerificationToken]").first().attr("value");
```

4. This may be the most important. I expect there's a page which redirects your browser to the URL defined in `ReturnUrl`. Jsoup can't handle javascript redirections so you  have to request that page manually. Actually that's what you browser would do anyway - make another request with latest cookies. You're on the right track, so at the end of your code you should additionally get the page you want with obtained cookies:

```
 cookies.putAll(homePage.cookies());// get the cookies after successful login
 Connection.Response finalPage = Jsoup.connect(returnUrl) //this should be the URL of the page you want to visit in the first place
   .cookies(cookies)
   .userAgent(USER_AGENT)
   .execute();
```

EDIT:
Oh, these really are correct credentials. But I see in Network tab of Chrome debugger there's more going on and more redirections. It's complicated as parts of new URL are generated by Javascript. To beat Jsoup's limitations try using Selenium Webdriver.